# Command bindings doesn't work when other data bindings works

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, binding, wpf-controls

I am using the [Jarloo's calendar control](http://www.jarloo.com/wpf-calendar-control/) and add some changes on it to fulfil my needs. I've been struggling with this for a long time now and I've no idea on what could possibly be the cause of my problems.

So, my problem is that none of my Command's bindings are working.

```
<ListView Background="White"
          SelectionMode="Single"
          dd:DragDrop.DropHandler="{Binding}" 
          dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="True"
          dd:DragDrop.UseDefaultDragAdorner="True" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Typologies}" 
          IsEnabled="{Binding Enabled}">
    <ListView.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="Delete" Command="{Binding CancelDispatchCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem}"/>
    </ListView.InputBindings>
....
</ListView>
```

Here, the keybinding is not working BUT the `{Binding Typologies}` and other DATA bindings are all working well. This led me to think that it is not a datacontext issue.

```
<Button DockPanel.Dock="Left" Margin="0,0,10,0" Content="&lt;&lt;" Command="{Binding ChangeDateCmd}" CommandParameter="YEAR,PREV"/>
```

Here again, my command binding is not working at all while this :

```
<TextBlock Padding="5" Text="{Binding TargetDate, Converter={StaticResource DateConverter}, ConverterParameter=MONTH}"/>
```

is working totally fine...

In day.cs :

```
private ICommand cancelDispatchCommand;
public ICommand CancelDispatchCommand
{
    get
    {
        return cancelDispatchCommand = cancelDispatchCommand ?? new ActionCommand((o) => CancelDispatch(o));
    }
}
```

In calendar.cs :

```
ICommand changeDateCmd;
public ICommand ChangeDateCmd
{
    get
    {
        return changeDateCmd = changeDateCmd ?? new ActionCommand((o) => ChangeDate(o));
    }
}
```

Comment: Try RelativeSource AncestorType ListView and use its DataContext and let know if it is working.

Comment: @Maximus Sorry i forgot to say I've already tried it ...
This is not working as well : `<KeyBinding Key="Delete" Command="{Binding DataContext.CancelDispatchCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem}"/>` :(

Comment: Any error in output window?

Comment: @Maximus Well thanks... Apparently the issue came from the fact that it couldn't load Microsoft.Expressions.Interactions 4.5 so I had to downgrade the reference to the 4.0 version ....

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use {Binding } with the command name.

[Here](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/commands/implementing-custom-commands/) is an example